# Spacemacs home buffer not showing?

Tags: spacemacs

If I start Spacemacs, I don't see the homescreen. I saw it for a while after my first install, so I think it might be something I've changed it my dotfile. However, the only values I found that seem to match the startup screen should be enabled:

```
dotspacemacs-startup-banner 'official
dotspacemacs-startup-lists '(recents projects)
dotspacemacs-startup-recent-list-size 5
```

Is there anything else in my dotfile that could be messing with this? I posted my dotfile for reference at https://gist.github.com/JuanCaicedo/9dd65f7c06618ca0b5409f5dcc18215f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your dotfile:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] 'silence)
```

should be in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function instead of `dotspacemacs/user-init` function.

`dotspacemacs/user-init` function is called before any package is actually loaded whereas `dotspacemacs/user-config` is called after. In your case you need the variable `evil-motion-state-map` to be defined so you have to put the expression in `user-config`.

Sometimes due to lazy loading even in `dotspacemacs/user-config` the variable may not be available, in those cases you have to use the macro `eval-after-load` or `with-eval-after-load` (if you are using emacs 24.4+).

To detect the error open the messages buffer with `SPC b b mess RET` and search for `error`.