# How to disable mouse in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, mouse

I'd like to completely disable my mouse in Spacemacs. Following the advice in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21534/spacemacs-home-buffer-not-showing/21539#21539), I set up the following in my .spacemacs file as

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration. You are free to put any user code."
  ;;(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
  (add-hook 'change-major-mode-after-body-hook 'fci-mode)
  (neotree-show)
  (with-eval-after-load FILE
    ;; don't jump the cursor around in the window on clicking
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] 'silence)
    ;; also avoid any '<mouse-1> is undefined' when setting to 'undefined
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map [mouse-1] 'silence)
    )
  )
```

I see this in the Help menu that `FILE`

> FILE is normally a feature name, but it can also be a file name,
>   in case that file does not provide any feature.

But I'm not sure what value I should use here.

Comment: You need to find out what file defines `evil-motion-state-map`. You can probably find out with the help of `C-h v`. At the end of that file, there will most likely be a line `(provide 'FEATURE)`. That feature name is what you should use. (Why am I not making this an answer? Because I am not really answering the question; I am only pointing the way to the answer.)

Comment: Teach a man to fish ;) I found `evil-motion-state-map is a variable defined in 'evil-states.el'.` However if I change `FILE` to `evil-states.el` and reload my dotfile, I can still use click with the mouse

Answer (score 4):

According to your example you don't need the function `with-eval-after-load`.
In Spacemacs it works simple like that:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "…"
  ;; …
  ;; dummy silence definition
  (defun silence ()
    (interactive))
  ;; don't jump the cursor around in the window on clicking
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] 'silence)
  ;; also avoid any '<mouse-1> is undefined' when setting to 'undefined
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map [mouse-1] 'silence))
```

To get it working for me I had to add the definition of `silence` before [like Marek Kubica did](https://xivilization.net/~marek/blog/2015/06/22/disabling-mouse-in-spacemacs/).

Comment: thanks, your solution definitely works and should been marked as solution

Comment: This answer worked great!

Comment: Actually, I've unaccepted this because for me it works for a while after I either start spacemacs or resync my dotfile. After a while the change disappears though. Any idea why that could be?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out my recently-published [disable-mouse](https://github.com/purcell/disable-mouse) package.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :/

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more specific information, or maybe even file a quick issue on github?

Answer (score 2):

I used an approach that was almost the same as @tasmo provided above

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map [down-mouse-1] 'ignore)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map [mouse-1] 'ignore)
```

But for the current Spacemacs `0.300` (at `develop` branch), it stops working if I switch buffer or open a new file unless reloading the dot file. There is another way to *completely* disable all mouse interactions -- turn off the `xterm-mouse-mode`:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
    (xterm-mouse-mode 0)
)
```

Comment: I'm using 0.300 without those problem :/ The other thing I ended up doing is  `(dolist (mouse '("<down-mouse-1>" "<mouse-1>"))
    (global-unset-key (kbd mouse)))`. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: https://github.com/purcell/disable-mouse seems like a better solution

Comment: `0.300.00@26.3 (spacemacs)` this works perfectly to disable mouse clicks when running emacs in a shell, thank you Chris!

Comment: (xterm-mouse-mode 0) worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `evil-motion-state-map` turns out to be defined in `"evil-state.el"`, as you have discovered. So you need to ensure that your code is run after that file is loaded.

Now `with-eval-after-load` is just a thin wrapper around `eval-after-load`. The latter documents the use of the `FILE` argument more carefully. If you read it, you will realize that using `"evil-states"` is more likely to succeed than using `"evil-states.el"`. Even better, however, is to use `'evil-states` (note the single quote). For, looking at [the source](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/src/41aa7c5943d9ecd3e19ff6e91b4339c929fb2b1f/evil-states.el?fileviewer=file-view-default), I notice the expected line `(provide 'evil-states)` at the bottom.

To expand a bit on this, it is likely that the file is going to be loaded via `(require 'evil-states)`. This will in turn become a call to `(load "evil-states")` – note the lack of the `.el` extension. The code reponsible for loading will then look for code to run in the variable `after-load-alist`. It will look for entries specified with the file name *as provided*, namely `"evil-states"`, and it will look for entries with the symbol `evil-states`, because the file executed `(provide 'evil-states)`. But it will *not* look for `"evil-states.el"`.

Comment: I submitted the incomplete documentation of `with-eval-after-load` as an [emacs bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23258).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! However, if I try this, it doesn't work as I first load Spacemacs. The changes do apply if I resync my dotfile though. It also added a ton of time to my startup time?

Comment: Well, since I don't use spacemacs myself, and don't know how it works, I can't help you there. Nor do I know what you mean by “resync my dotfile”. But this I do know: Under no reasonable circumstance will a `with-eval-after-load` whose body simply (re)defines two keys lead to a noticable startup time. The reason for that must be elsewhere.