# Middle-click copy/paste link to Spacemacs in Helm Org Insert Link

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, helm, x-window

I have just entered the Spacemacs ecosystem with no prior Emacs experience.

I want to copy paste a link with my mouse from my X clipboard using middle-click in Spacemacs Org mode.
I have selected the link in my browser with double-clicking (or with `C-c`).

In Spacemacs, editing `emacs-notes.org`, I type `C-c l` and the following appears:

[image: screenshot-HELM-Org-Insert-Link]

I can type the http://.../ with the yellow-filled-box cursor ([image: screenshot-HELM-Org-Insert-Link-cursor]), but I cannot use the mouse middle-click (or `C-v`) to paste it from my X clipboard and save me from all the typing.

`~/.spacemacs` contains:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (xterm-mouse-mode -1)) ;; copy paste with mouse middle button from X
```

Nevertheless, when I middle-click, the system pastes the link elsewhere (e.g. in the `emacs-notes.org` buffer).
I have also tried [disabling the mouse](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/how-to-disable-mouse-in-spacemacs) but this doesn't work either.

How can I paste a link from the X clipboard in the yellow-filled-boxed using the mouse (or a keyboard shortcut)?

If there are other ways to do this, I'd like to learn them.

Comment: So I had a similarish situation today.
I was trying to paste a link I got from chromes address bar into spacemacs document in org mode using SPC m i l.
My spacemacs was in cygwin's terminal emacs in a tmux session in a mintty terminal in cygwin in windows 10. So there were many layers in which something might go wrong. But just messing around I found out I can get the terminals(mintty) right click menu (either tmux or emacs or spacemacs disabled the terminals right click menu for some reason) by holding shift and then right clicking. Also emacs has a menu you can bring up if you hold alt and r

Comment: `xterm-mouse-mode` only affects the behavior of Emacs when running inside a terminal emulator, not in GUI frames (like the one that appears in the image above).

Comment: Have you tried middle clicking on the minibuffer?

Comment: I always do C-y in that box. Hope that helps you.