# Is there a way to disable all mouse functionality in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I have tried doing this which I found in another StackExchange post but it doesn't work for me, is there another way to disable the mouse in spacemacs completely, I use evil mode, thanks.

[How to disable mouse in Spacemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/how-to-disable-mouse-in-spacemacs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Can you just use https://github.com/purcell/disable-mouse as an additional package?

Comment: I have tried that. After installing disable-mouse the mouse was still being used by spacemacs. When I restarted spacemacs I saw a line stating: deleting disable-mouse. Mouse was still being used afterwards. @Ryan

Comment: add it to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` and make sure you have `(global-disable-mouse-mode)` in your configuration.

Comment: Where do I put (global-disable-mouse-mode), which file and what section? @Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(
   disable-mouse
)
```

And put the following in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section of your `.spacemacs` file:

```
(global-disable-mouse-mode)
```

That should disable the mouse for everything in Emacs.

Comment: I tried that on two different machines, mouse still works :(

Comment: In the terminal (`emacs -nw`), I managed to do the trick by setting `(xterm-mouse-mode -1)` _inside_ `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

Comment: @Ryan I have tried the above but mouse still works, something else must be missing or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This finally worked for me: ```(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
    (xterm-mouse-mode 0)
)``` I got this from: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/how-to-disable-mouse-in-spacemacs